# How to add extra title component to nested plots based on groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to plot some forestplots using values that fall into two variables and four separate groups. Unfortunately when it comes to titling I'm able to use only component of one variable. I've checked multiple solutions and other topics on stack/google but I can't find any sufficient answer. Here's my data:

```
                        X1 X2   X3   X4           X5          X6       X7        X8       X9
1                  Average  7    A Gamma 0.0029603231 0.001384471 1.002965 1.0002468 1.005690
2                  Average  7    A Theta 0.0065349553 0.001550613 1.006556 1.0035019 1.009620
3                  Average  7    B Gamma 0.0016303931 0.001553930 1.001632 0.9985857 1.004687
4                  Average  7    B Theta 0.0075093350 0.002020529 1.007538 1.0035554 1.011536
5  Variable_1               7    A Gamma 0.0039225073 0.001286516 1.003930 1.0014020 1.006465
6  Variable_1               7    A Theta 0.0069761147 0.001626288 1.007001 1.0037958 1.010215
7  Variable_1               7    B Gamma 0.0018554406 0.001802965 1.001857 0.9983231 1.005404
8  Variable_1               7    B Theta 0.0077743420 0.002102507 1.007805 1.0036602 1.011966
9  Variable_2               7    A Gamma 0.0009682313 0.002167431 1.000969 0.9967255 1.005230
10 Variable_2               7    A Theta 0.0021228624 0.005143065 1.002125 0.9920742 1.012278
11 Variable_2               7    B Gamma 0.0009803548 0.003064218 1.000981 0.9949872 1.007011
12 Variable_2               7    B Theta 0.0043084374 0.007307093 1.004318 0.9900368 1.018805
```

Here's my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

plots <- my_data %>%
  group_by(X3, X4) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plot = map2(data, X3,  
                     ~ggplot(data = ., aes(x=X1, y=X7, ymin=X8, ymax=X9)) +
                           geom_linerange( size=8, colour="#a6d8f0") +
                           geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1), lty=1) +
                           geom_point(size=3, shape=21, fill="#008fd5", colour = "white", stroke = 1) +
                           scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.95, 1.05)) +
                           coord_flip() +
                           ggtitle(.y) +
                           theme_minimal()))
```

Which gives me corresponding title only for A/B groups if I map X3. Gamma/Theta groups title if I map X4. I'd like to obtain plots with all title components combination A/Gamma, A/Theta, B/Gamma, B/Theta. Adding anything extra in my case gives me an error or static title component for all plots. Or i should just join X3 and X4 into one so i result with one variable and four groups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `purrr::pmap()` to iterate over more than 2 elements:

```
plots <- dat %>%
  group_by(X3, X4) %>%
  nest() %>%
  mutate(plot = pmap(list(data, X3, X4), 
                     ~ggplot(data = ..1, aes(x=X1, y=X7, ymin=X8, ymax=X9)) +
                       geom_linerange( size=8, colour="#a6d8f0") +
                       geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1), lty=1) +
                       geom_point(size=3, shape=21, fill="#008fd5", colour = "white", stroke = 1) +
                       scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0.95, 1.05)) +
                       coord_flip() +
                       ggtitle(paste0(..2, "/", ..3)) +
                       theme_minimal()))
```

The `..index` references the position of a element in the list passed to `pmap()`

Comment: Neat and clean, thank you! Will read documentation next time more carefuly. @ edit: Oh Nate, any ideas if i try to plot only average values with labels refering to it?

Comment: Yea I would make a new data frame with the group averages. Not sure if you want that to be grouped by x-axis breaks or the split grouping. And then I would float the labels on a edge of the plots like [I do here](https://www.natedayta.com/2018/11/15/how-to-float-ggplot2-s-geom-label/)